# Carregar uma janela apenas uma vez depois de recarregado o site em asp.net C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, localstorage

Tendo esta janela [image: esta janela] quando se acede a um site pela primeira vez, como faço para aparecer apenas uma vez mesmo depois de recarregado o website ou o utilizador voltar a página inicial e não aparecer isto de novo?

```
<input type="radio" id="rd">
    <div class="bg">
        <div class="box">
            <p class="p1">Bem-vindo</p>
            <p class="p1">á</p>
            <p class="p1">DOMO® Portugal</p>
            <p class="p2">Tornamos o seu sonho realidade</p>
            <label for="rd">Visitar</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Tenho pesquisado algo sobre localstorage mas não percebo como se faz.

EDIT:

Já descobri a solução nesta pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899415/show-a-div-only-once-per-time-the-user-is-on-the-site

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `sessionstorage`, ele terá valor até que o usuário feche o navegador, após isso será destruído

```
    $(function() {  
        var deveExibirModal = sessionStorage.getItem('deveExibirModal');        
        if(deveExibirModal != undefined && deveExibirModal != "nao"{ 
            $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
                height: 140,
                close: function( event, ui ) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem('deveExibirModal', 'nao');               
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Agora se deseja controlar isso de uma forma diferente há o `localstorage` seu valor só será destruído por código ou caso o usuário faça limpeza ou desinstale o navegador

```
$(function() {  

    var dataVencimento = localStorage.getItem('dataVencimento');

    if(dataVencimento < hoje)
    {
        localStorage.removeItem("deveExibirModal");
        localStorage.removeItem("dataVencimento");
    }       

    var deveExibirModal = localStorage.getItem('deveExibirModal');

    if(deveExibirModal != undefined && deveExibirModal != "nao"{ 
        $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
            height: 140,
            close: function( event, ui ) {
                localStorage.setItem('deveExibirModal', 'nao');
                localStorage.setItem('dataVencimento', 'sua_data');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Você pode ler mais na [documentação](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Até pode ser uma boa ideia.. só que eu não possuo nenhum Modal.. tudo o que eu tenho está no codigo que coloquei na pergunta.. Aquele script que coloquei fui buscar a uma outra pergunta mas não funciona no meu projeto

Comment: Não faz sentido você perguntar algo, adicionar um código que não é seu.